# How do I test catching HTTP errors in Angular

Tags: angular, jasmine

I have a function as below in Angular:

```
getData(payload):any {
  return this.http.post(url,payload).catch(err => this.handleError());
}
```

How do I write a test case to enter the catch block using Jasmine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Jasmine's spies. It would look something like this:

```
describe('when there is an error', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    const error = new Error()
    spyOn(http, 'post').and.returnValue(of(error));
    spyOn(service, 'handleError').and.callThrough();

    service.getData({});
  });

  it('should handle the error', () => {
    expect(service.handleError).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
})
```

Jasmine's spies allow us to mock a return value like an error from an HTTP request, and test out alternative paths in our code. That's what `returnValue` is doing.

`callThrough` simply tells Jasmine to watch for calls of the actual implementation of the function. In the case of `handleError` we simply want to be sure it runs when there's an error.

All `toHaveBeenCalled` does is returns true if our spy was actually called.

There's also `toHaveBeenCalledWith` where you can test to ensure that your code was called with specific arguments. In this case, maybe you actually want to pass the error object to `handleError`.

Comment: It should be using `throwError` rather than `of`, because `of` will return OK observable, and the function won't be called...